# Nvidia OpenGL graphics and OpenCL breaking after update, before reboot

Tags: nvidia

I've had this problem for a long time. *Some* updates break my 3D graphics. I can still use the system —and that's helpful because I'm doing work— but when I try to play any games, nothing works.

Here's the rough scenario:

1. I start with working 2D and 3D graphics
2. I install updates with `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
3. I suspend and resume.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for several days.
5. 3D graphics stop working.
6. I slave away until my fingers bleed ... finally reboot and everything works again.

I've been going through this for *years*. Over multiple major versions of Ubuntu and the Nvidia driver. The problem is I'm doing more 3D/CAD for work than I had been.

Rebooting isn't the end of the world —there are some good arguments for it— but it does mean stepping away from the computer for an additional couple of minutes and needing to reinitialise my working environment, losing active debugging states, etc. I want to avoid it.

So I'm looking for one of three things:

- Can I stop this happening in the future?
- Can I reinitialise the Nvidia driver with an active X server?
- Can I "hibernate" my applications and reboot the hardware/drivers/etc separately? (Not the same as a real hibernate)

---

`glxinfo` isn't particularly useful here but it does show you what I'm up against.

```
name of display: :0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  79
  Current serial number in output stream:  80
```

This sort of error is shared by people with botched installations. I have to be very clear here. My installation is fine most of the time. Off a fresh boot it's great.

I was three weeks into this session (with ~150 sleep-resume cycles and 40+ `dist-upgrades`) before it broke.